# NativeScript: router-outlet doesn't work

Tags: angular, nativescript, router-outlet

I follow this [official example](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-navigation.html#router-outlet) in my app that shows how a `<router-outlet>` is implemented in {N}. The only difference in my app is that I want to use it within a modal page. But instead of the `<router-outlet>` element within the modal, it loads the content as new pages.

#### ModalComponent

```js
...
@Component({
    selector: "modal",
    template: `
        <StackLayout>
            <StackLayout>
                <Button text="First" [nsRouterLink]="['/first']"></Button>
                <Button text="Second" [nsRouterLink]="['/second']"></Button>
            </StackLayout>

            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class ModalComponent {
    constructor(private page:Page, public params:ModalDialogParams) {
        // ..
    }
}
```

#### app.routing.ts

```js
...
export const routes:Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" },
    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
    { path: "modal", component: ModalComponent },
    { path: "first", component: FirstComponent },
    { path: "second", component: SecondComponent }
];

export const dynamicComponents = [
    ModalComponent,
    FirstComponent,
    SecondComponent
];
...
```

#### app.module.ts

```js
...
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ...dynamicComponents
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ...dynamicComponents
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Any idea why `/first` and `/second` navigates to a new page instead of loading the into router-outlet of the modal?

**UPDATE**:

This seems to be a bug. See my answer below.

Comment: I am not using the   `NativeScriptRouterModule` but I am doing the same thing using `RouterModule` from `@angular/router` and it is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created clean {N} + Angular projects and made tests.
Turns out if the app is bootstrapped with a component that has a `<page-router-outlet>`; it ignores any `<router-outlet>` within a (sub) page/component and `nsRouteLink` will **navigate** to a new page instead of loading the target component in the router-outlet.

Tests without `<page-router-outlet>` (in the root component) worked as expected.

I think this is a **bug** since I don't see any notice about having to use either one of `<page-router-outlet>` or `<router-outlet>` in the documentation (wouldn't make any sense anyway).

UPDATE: Opened an [issue here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/609).

UPDATE 2: Nested routers (`<router-outlet>` with `<page-router-outlet>` in the root) should define `children` to work. But if the `<router-outlet>` is in a modal, it won't work (throws `Error: No provider for ModalDialogParams!`). This is definitely a bug, [confirmed here](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/609#issuecomment-270593024).

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    path: 'modal',
    component: ModalComponent,
    children: [
        { path: "first", component: FirstComponent },
        { path: "second", component: SecondComponent }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app.module.ts file make following changes to do it without `NativeScriptRouterModule`:

```
  import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';  

@NgModule({
imports: [...,RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        ...dynamicComponents
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ...dynamicComponents
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When you close the modal you should also navigate back to the modal route because the activated route will be `/first` or `/second` and you want the activated route to be `/modal` after the modal has disappeared.

Comment: This is a NativeScript app. I cannot remove those modules. Besides, navigating back is not the problem. I need `/first` and `/second` to be loaded within `<router-outlet>`.